# Can we take individual derivative of piecewise function if the function is continuous and differentiable?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

Can we take individual derivative of piecewise function if the function is continuous and differentiable?

Suppose a function $f(x)$ is defined in such a way that it's definition changes at some particular point, say $x = a$. If it's given a priori that $f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable at point $x = a$, can we just individually take derivative of one of the function and find it's value at $x = a$?

For example, $$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
      x^2 & \text{if}\ x \geq 1 \\
      2x - 1 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}$$

This function is continuous and differentiable at $x=1$. Here the derivative also equals $$2 = 2(1) \text{ (derivative of } x^2 \text{ at 1}) = 2 \text{ (derivative of } 2x \text{ at 1})$$

Is this true for all functions given to be continuous and differentiable at some point (that value of individual derivative equals actual derivative)?

Comment: I don't understand what is "all functions" in last claim. If $f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable in point $x=a$, then $f(a-0)=f(a)=f(a+0)$, $f'(a-0)=f'(a+0)$, where $g(a\pm 0)=\lim_{x\to a\pm 0} g(x)$. Also if $g(x)$ is continuous and differentiable at $x=f(a)$ and $f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable at $x=a$ then $g(f(x))$ is continuous and differentiable at $x=a$.

Comment: If $f(x) = \begin{cases} f_1(x) & \text{if}\ x \geq a; \\ f_2(x) & \text{otherwise}   \end{cases}$, then for $f(x)$ to be continuous and differentiable following statements must be satisfied: $\lim_{x\to a+0} f_1(x)=f_1(a)=\lim_{x\to a-0} f_2(x)$, $\lim_{x\to a+0} f_1'(x)=\lim_{x\to a-0}f_2'(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is (almost) true. For:
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
g(x) &\text{if }x\geq a\\
h(x) &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
and both $g,h$ are defined and continuous at $x=a$, then we must have:
$$
f\text{ is continuous at }a\iff g(a)=h(x)
$$
Now regarding $f$ being differentiable at $a$, we have:
$$
\text{$g$ and $h$ are differentiable at $a$}\\
\quad\\
\Downarrow\\
\quad\\
\begin{bmatrix}
g'(a)=h'(a)=\alpha\\
\Updownarrow\\
f\text{ is differentiable at }a\\
\text{ and }\\
f'(a)=\alpha
\end{bmatrix}
$$

BUT if either $g$ or $h$ is not differentiable at $a$ (or for instance $h$ is not defined there), then you need to check the actual definition of being differentiable in detail to figure out what happens there.

Comment: Thank you very much. Does it also mean that if a function is given to be continuous at point $x = a$ and both $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are differentiable at $a$, and $g'(a) = h'(a)$, then the function $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x = a$?

Comment: @MangoPizza: Yes, you are correct. I updated my post to reflect this. I hope it is clearer now!

Comment: Thank you, what is $cg'(a)$?

Comment: @MangoPizza: A typo 